# Resetting the specific authorizations of one folder and it's childs on SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, authorization

My SharePoint O365 site authorizations are a bit messed-up.

Files have been moved across the site. And while being moved, they have kept their previous authorizations. And this lead those files to have specific authorizations.

I'd like to clear all those specific authorizations at once. From the top of one folder to the bottom of all its childs (be them folders or files).

Is there are a simple (i.e. one-click) way for doing this ?

[Edit]I'm on the client-side and don't have access to the server-side.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below PowerShell Command to remove all unique permissions set everywhere(subsites/lists/libraries/list items/library files/folders...) on a site collection.

For Reference: [How to reset the specific library permission including all subfolders on SharePoint?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/254869/how-to-reset-the-specific-library-permission-inclu.html)

PowerShell Commands:

```
 #Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
 Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
 Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
      
 #To call a non-generic Load Method
 Function Invoke-LoadMethod() {
     Param(
             [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientObject]$Object = $(throw "Please provide a Client Object"), [string]$PropertyName
          )
    $Ctx = $Object.Context
    $Load = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext].GetMethod("Load")
    $Type = $Object.GetType()
    $ClientLoad = $Load.MakeGenericMethod($Type)
       
    $Parameter = [System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::Parameter(($Type), $Type.Name)
    $Expression = [System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::Lambda([System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::Convert([System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::PropertyOrField($Parameter,$PropertyName),[System.Object] ), $($Parameter))
    $ExpressionArray = [System.Array]::CreateInstance($Expression.GetType(), 1)
    $ExpressionArray.SetValue($Expression, 0)
    $ClientLoad.Invoke($Ctx,@($Object,$ExpressionArray))
 }
     
 #Function to Delete Unique Permission from a Web and its content
 Function Reset-SPOUniquePermission([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web]$Web)
 {
     Write-host -f Magenta "`nSearching Unique Permissions on the Site:"$web.Url
         
     #Check if the given site is using unique permissions
     Invoke-LoadMethod -Object $Web -PropertyName "HasUniqueRoleAssignments"
     $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
         
     #Get the Root Web
     $RootWeb = $ctx.site.RootWeb
     $Ctx.Load($RootWeb)
     $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
     
     ### Reset broken inheritance on the Web
     If($Web.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -and $Web.ID -ne $RootWeb.ID)
     {
         #powershell to delete unique permissions of a subsite in sharepoint online
         $Web.ResetRoleInheritance()
         $Web.Update()
         $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()   
         Write-host -f Green "`t Unique Permissions Removed from the Site: $SiteURL!"
     }
             
     ### Reset unique permission in Lists
     Write-host -f Magenta "`t Searching Unique Permissions on the Lists"
     $Lists =  $Web.Lists
     $Ctx.Load($Lists)
     $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
     
     #Exclude system lists
     $ExcludedLists = @("App Packages","appdata","appfiles","Apps in Testing","Cache Profiles","Composed Looks","Content and Structure Reports","Content type publishing error log","Converted Forms",
      "Device Channels","Form Templates","fpdatasources","Get started with Apps for Office and SharePoint","List Template Gallery", "Long Running Operation Status","Maintenance Log Library", "Style Library",
      ,"Master Docs","Master Page Gallery","MicroFeed","NintexFormXml","Quick Deploy Items","Relationships List","Reusable Content","Search Config List", "Solution Gallery", "Site Collection Images",
      "Suggested Content Browser Locations","TaxonomyHiddenList","User Information List","Web Part Gallery","wfpub","wfsvc","Workflow History","Workflow Tasks", "Preservation Hold Library")
         
     #Iterate through each list
     ForEach($List in $Lists)
     {
         $Ctx.Load($List)
         $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
     
         If($ExcludedLists -NotContains $List.Title -and $List.Hidden -eq $false)
         {
             #Check if the given site is using unique permissions
             Invoke-LoadMethod -Object $List -PropertyName "HasUniqueRoleAssignments"
             $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
      
             #Reset broken inheritance of the list
             If($List.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
             {
                 #delete unique permissions of a subsite in sharepoint online powershell
                 $List.ResetRoleInheritance()
                 $List.Update()
                 $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()   
                 Write-host -f Green "`t`tUnique Permissions Removed from the List: '$($List.Title)'"
             }
     
             Write-host -f Magenta "`t`t Searching Unique Permissions on the Lists Items of '$($List.Title)'"
     
             #Query to batch process
             $Query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
             $Query.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><RowLimit>2000</RowLimit></View>"
     
             ### Reset unique permission on List items
             Do { 
                 #Get all items from the list - in batches
                 $ListItems = $List.GetItems($Query)
                 $Ctx.Load($ListItems)
                 $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
                
                 $Query.ListItemCollectionPosition = $ListItems.ListItemCollectionPosition
       
                 #Loop through each List item
                 ForEach($ListItem in $ListItems)
                 {
                     Invoke-LoadMethod -Object $ListItem -PropertyName "HasUniqueRoleAssignments"
                     $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
                     if ($ListItem.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $true)
                     {
                         #Reset Permission Inheritance
                         $ListItem.ResetRoleInheritance()
                         Write-host  -ForegroundColor Green "`t`t`t Unique Permissions Removed and Inheritence Restored on Item ID:" $ListItem.ID
                     }
                 }
                 $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
             } While ($Query.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)
         }
     }
     
     #Process each subsite in the site
     $Subsites = $Web.Webs
     $Ctx.Load($Subsites)
     $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()       
     Foreach ($SubSite in $Subsites)
     {
         #Call the function Recursively
         Reset-SPOUniquePermission($Subsite)
     }
 }
     
 #Config Parameters
 $SiteURL= "https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxxx"
      
 #Get Credentials to connect
 $Cred = Get-Credential
      
 Try {
     #Setup the context
     $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
     $Ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.UserName,$Cred.Password)
          
     #Get the Web
     $Web = $Ctx.Web
     $Ctx.Load($Web)
     $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
         
     #Call the function to delete unique permission from all sites in the site collection
     Reset-SPOUniquePermission $Web
 }
 Catch {
     write-host -f Red "Error:" $_.Exception.Message
 }
```

Comment: I'm on the client-side. Your script is tu be executed at server-side ?